# socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) using snmp4j in android

Tags: android, snmp, permission-denied, snmp4j

I'm working on an android application and in that, I need to know the other device status using SNMP Oid which is in the same network.
I have followed the example from the below link.
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/snmp4j/snmp-walk-example-using-snmp4j/

But I was ended up with the below exception.
socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I have observed that I'm getting this exception when I'm creating the object of DefaultUdpTransportMapping()
Line number 47 from the above link.

I have added INTERNET, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions also.
I'm running the application on a real device.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: After doing the research on this issue, it is an error 13 issue in Android. I'm checking the application on an Android Q device. 
Is it restricted in Android Q?

Comment: The problem with my application is with internet permission. Now I have resolved it, but now I'm getting a response as a empty object.